# Stripe Cancel Subscription Error

Tags: stripe-payments

I am writing the code to cancel subscription so following is the code

```
var objSubscriptionService = new StripeSubscriptionService(stripekey);
objSubscriptionService.Cancel(ClientID, planId, true);
```

But I am getting error

> Message "Customer  does not have a subscription with ID "

But my customer is attached with plan. I can see it on stripe dashboard.

What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using [Stripe.NET](https://github.com/jaymedavis/stripe.net) library based on your code. In that case, to cancel a subscription you need to provide the subscription id `sub_XXX` not the plan id here as you can see on his [documentation](https://github.com/jaymedavis/stripe.net#canceling-a-subscription)

```
var subscriptionService = new StripeSubscriptionService();
subscriptionService.Cancel(*customerId*, *subscriptionId*); // optional cancelAtPeriodEnd flag
```

You can retrieve that subscription id on the [Customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api#customer_object) object or listing all the customer's subscription as explained [here](https://github.com/jaymedavis/stripe.net#list-all-subscriptions-for-a-customer):

```
var subscriptionService = new StripeSubscriptionService();
IEnumerable<StripeSubscription> response = customerService.List(*customerId*); // optional StripeListOptions
```